# How to configure Resource Editor for Codename One in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

Opening the `theme.res` with Resource Editor throws the following error:

> Error opening resource editor: Cannot run program "E:\Eclipse\Android eclipse\sdk\bin\java.exe" (in directory "E:\Eclipse\Android eclipse\sdk\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid.

Comment: You have a space somewhere in the path?

Comment: Formatting, IDE name

Answer (score 0):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to a valid JDK path, make sure the java.exe file of that JDK is in the path as well. Make sure the new Codename One project uses that SDK.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because the space in the directory name "Android eclipse"